# parsing html page with net http

Tags: ruby

In a previous question I have found an answer for a hacked - but working - way to parse the title from a page using

```
 url = %x(curl http://google.com)
 simian = curl.match(/<title>(.*)<\/title>/)[1]
 puts simian
```

now I wanted to know if there is a better way by using a ruby standard library like net/http to fetch the url (in lieu of curl).

Another issue is that if the pages has some non standard characters in the title it doesn't parse it and curl.match cannot be completed.  I have tried

```
 simian = s.encode('UTF-8') and then
 simian = curl.match(/<title>(.*)<\/title>/)[1]
```

but it shows weird characters like 1# 
thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nokogiri is probably the simplest solution:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.google.com'))
elt = doc.xpath('//title').first
puts elt.text() if !elt.nil?
```

Comment: Hi Sebastien, this is true and it works but even Nokogiri fails in this case doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://zales.1.ai'))  nokotest2.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: If the page you are trying to access has no title, then the `xpath` query will return nil, hence the error.

Comment: I have edited to add a nil check, which is pretty much the best you can do if there is no title! ;)